# The best way to load Keras model?

Tags: python, keras

I use python + keras to train and load model as below:

```
    # create and fit the LSTM network
    if sys.argv[1] == 'train':
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
        # model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
        model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
        model.save_weights(sys.argv[3])
        model.save('my_model.h5', overwrite=True)
    else:
        print("Loading model %s" % sys.argv[3])
        model = load_model(sys.argv[3])
```

So, my program take so much time to load a model trained, can you help me improve this issue?

Comment: You are already saving weights at time of training. Then at time of load model just create empty model like train one and then set it's weight using set_weights method which will set weights in model which you generated at time of training.

Comment: It's not necessary to create a whole new empty model at time of loading, except for in certain circumstances when load_model doesn't work (load_model loads weights and the model architecture). In terms of improving performance though, model.save already saves the model architecture and weights, so you could remove your save_weights line